# For loop repeat to get larger json data with no duplicate in Python

Tags: python, json, duplicates, repeat

I tried to repeat 10times of json file which add 1~10 at element called "ProcessGuid" in each iteration via the following code

```
import json
file = open("D:/Test/test.json",'r',encoding='utf-8')
papers = []
for line in file.readlines():
    dic = json.loads(line)
    papers.append(dic)
    
result_int = papers
string_name = list(map(str, range(1,10)))
    
for element in string_name:
    result = []
    result = result_int
    processlist = []
    for i in range(len(result)):
        (result[i])['Event']['EventData']['ProcessGuid'] = str((result[i])['Event']['EventData']['ProcessGuid'])+element
    
    with open("D:/Test/process_"+str(element)+".json", 'w', encoding ='utf8') as json_file:
        json.dump(result, json_file, ensure_ascii = False)
```

I though the result of data in each repeat would be like (suppose the origin data element of ProcessGuid is Hello)

```
1st repeat : ProcessGuid = Hello1
2nd repeat : ProcessGuid = Hello2
3rd repeat : ProcessGuid = Hello3
...
10th repeat : ProcessGuid = Hello10
```

But the result is the following

```
1st repeat : ProcessGuid = Hello1
2nd repeat : ProcessGuid = Hello12
3rd repeat : ProcessGuid = Hello123
...
10th repeat : ProcessGuid = Hello12345678910
```

Where do I get wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each `element`, the code appends to the same values.
If you only want to append each `element` once to the original values,
you could save the original values first:

```
base_values = [str(paper['Event']['EventData']['ProcessGuid']) for paper in papers]

for element in string_name:
    for i, paper in enumerate(papers):
        paper['Event']['EventData']['ProcessGuid'] = base_values[i] + element
    
    with open("D:/Test/process_" + str(element) + ".json", 'w', encoding ='utf8') as json_file:
        json.dump(papers, json_file, ensure_ascii = False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You keep overwriting result_int over and over again.

[How do I clone a list so that it doesn't change unexpectedly after assignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-do-i-clone-a-list-so-that-it-doesnt-change-unexpectedly-after-assignment)

Change:

```
result = list(result_int)
```